# Software Updater asking me to install updates but on Terminal nothing detected to upgrade

Tags: command-line, update-manager

I opened my laptop and saw a popup window informing me that there are updates and if I am willing to install them. I chose to not:

[image]

I opened the Terminal and run `sudo apt-get upgrade` but it did not install anything:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  libmm-glib0 libqmi-proxy modemmanager
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
```

So I went to the dash and  picked the Software Updater where I installed the updates.

Any logic explanation of this? I mean why the command line did not detect anything to upgrade?

Comment: They probably involved version-bumps etc. that required `sudo apt dist-upgrade`.....    Upgrade doesn't get all the updates of dist-upgrade..

Comment: `apt-get upgrade` rules state "under no
           circumstances are currently installed packages removed, or packages
           not already installed retrieved and installed. New versions of
           currently installed packages that cannot be upgraded without
           changing the install status of another package will be left at
           their current version."  (from `man apt-get`) .  it then says about dist-upgrade "in addition to performing the function of upgrade,
           also intelligently handles changing.."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *GUI*  (software updater) probably uses dist-upgrade instead of upgrade. The differences between upgrades options.

From the manual (`man apt-get`) it tells us for 'upgrade'

```
under no circumstances are currently installed packages removed, or
packages not already installed retrieved and installed. New versions of 
currently installed packages that cannot be upgraded without changing the 
install status of another package will be left at their current version.
```

and continues in the dist-upgrade section saying

```
in addition to performing the function of upgrade, also intelligently
handles changing dependencies with new versions of packages...
```

(copied from `man apt-get`)